# Aviary SDK Customization Issue

Tags: ios

hello i am using Aviary sdk in ios. I want to change Navigation bar color in aviary sdk.can anybody know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.aviary.com/ios/documentation#customization

Answer (score 0):

Included in the SDK folder is an Aviary Customizer ... you can edit quite a bit that way.

(it's an app that runs on your desk top, and allows customization.  Then, you save it to your xcode project and all drawing happens automatically!)